# How to analyse and identify directed graph relationships (between nodes) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I want to use Python to solve a graph theory problem (I am a complete novice to graph theory).

The data is in the following format:

```
edges = [('Child1', 'Parent1'), ('Child2', 'Parent2'), ('Child3', 'Parent1'), 
     ('Child4', 'Parent3'), ('Child2', 'Parent1')]
```

The relationships I need to analyse include finding that:

- Child2's parents are Parent1 and Parent2
- Parent1 is a parent to Child1, Child2 and Child3.

What is the best way to find the above listed relationships using Python?

Comment: What do you mean with *analyze*? What query/queries do you want to resolve? Topological sorting? shortest path? Eulerian cycle?

Comment: I would like to understand the directional links between the nodes. E.g. node A is a child of nodes B and C, and a parent of these nodes D, E, F.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged `networkx`, here's a solution using that library.

In the code below I create a directional graph and then add the edges from your list. Important: the first node in an edge will be the source node and the second node will be the target node,  i.e. the children will point to their parents.

To get the parents of a child I use [`out_edges`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.out_edges.html) and to get the children of a parent I use [`in_edges`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.in_edges.html). Note that both functions return a list of edges.

```
import networkx as nx

edges = [('Child1', 'Parent1'), ('Child2', 'Parent2'), ('Child3', 'Parent1'), 
     ('Child4', 'Parent3'), ('Child2', 'Parent1')]

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(edges)

print(G.out_edges('Child2'))  # parents of Child2
print(G.in_edges('Parent1'))  # children of Parent1
```

Output:

```
[('Child2', 'Parent2'), ('Child2', 'Parent1')]
[('Child2', 'Parent1'), ('Child1', 'Parent1'), ('Child3', 'Parent1')]
```

You can use list comprehension to get lists with individual children or parents.

```
temp = [edge[1] for edge in G.out_edges('Child2')]
print('Parents of Child2:', temp)

temp = [edge[0] for edge in G.in_edges('Parent1')]
print('Children of Parent1:', temp)
```

Output:

```
Parents of Child2: ['Parent2', 'Parent1']
Children of Parent1: ['Child2', 'Child1', 'Child3']
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the following:
`[('Child1', 'Parent1'), ('Child2', 'Parent2'), ('Child3', 'Parent1'), 
     ('Child4', 'Parent3'), ('Child2', 'Parent1')] --> [('Parent1',('Child1', 'Child2','Child3')), ('Parent2',('Child2')), ('Parent3',('Child4'))]`

Comment: @Dave That probably deserves a new question, but here's the solution anyway (in 2 lines): first `parents = sorted(list(set([edge[1] for edge in edges])))` and then `edges2 = [(p, tuple(sorted([e[0] for e in edges if e[1] == p]))) for p in parents]`. I know that's a rather ugly solution using list comprehension, so here's [a more readable way](http://pythonfiddle.com/a-new-list-of-edges) to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a mapping between parents and children:

```
>>> edges = [
...     ('Child1', 'Parent1'), ('Child2', 'Parent2'), ('Child3', 'Parent1'), 
...     ('Child4', 'Parent3'), ('Child2', 'Parent1')
... ]

>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> parents = defaultdict(list)  # Key: child, value: list of parents
>>> children = defaultdict(list)  # Key: parent, value: list of children
>>> for child, parent in edges:
...     parents[child].append(parent)
...     children[parent].append(child)
... 
>>> parents['Child2']  # Child2's parents are Parent1 and Parent2
['Parent2', 'Parent1']
>>> children['Parent1'] # Parent1 is a parent to Child1, Child2 and Child3.
['Child1', 'Child3', 'Child2']
```